# How to prepopulate text field with entity reference values

Tags: webforms

I have two element:

1. Entity reference autocomplete, will populate from Username (value from field name in user entity) Views Entity Reference.

By inputing this Entity Reference Outocomplete I can select username followed with field_first_name value.

2. Text Field (hopefully populated from Users field_first_name).

I know in advamced tabs, we can set default value using tokens, but i can not find any token matches with point 2 above.

Anyone please assist me how to achive it?

Thanks you before.